# is it good to use different collections in a database in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am going to do a project using nodejs and mongodb. We are designing the schema of database, we are not sure that whether we need to use different collections or same collection to store the data. Because each has its own pros and cons. 
If we use single collection, whenever the database is invoked, total collection will be loaded into memory which reduces the RAM capacity.If we use different collections then to retrieve data we need to write different queries. By using one collection retrieving will be easy and by using different collections application will become faster. We are confused whether to use single collection or multiple collections. Please Guide me which one is better.

Comment: you mean whether to use inline documents within some bigger document vs. putting those inner documents into a separate collection?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use different collections for different things. For example when you have users and articles in the systems, you usually create a "users" collection for users and "articles" collection for articles. You could create one collection called "objects" or something like that and put everything there but it would mean you would have to add some type fields and use it for searches and storage of data. You can use a single collection in the database but it would make the usage more complicated. Of course it would let you to load the entire collection at once but whether or not it is relevant for the performance of your application, that is something that would have to be profiled and tested to give your the performance impact for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, developers create the different collection for different things. Like for post management, people create 'post' collection and save the posts in post collection and same for users and all.

Using different collection for different purpose is a good pratices.

MongoDB is great at scaling horizontally. It can shard a collection across a dynamic cluster to produce a fast, querable collection of your data.

So having a smaller collection size is not really a pro and I am not sure where this theory comes that it is, it isn't in SQL and it isn't in MongoDB. The performance of sharding, if done well, should be relative to the performance of querying a single small collection of data (with a small overhead). If it isn't then you have setup your sharding wrong.

MongoDB is not great at scaling vertically, as @Sushant quoted, the ns size of MongoDB would be a serious limitation here. One thing that quote does not mention is that index size and count also effect the ns size hence why it describes that:

> By default MongoDB has a limit of approximately 24,000 namespaces per
>   database. Each namespace is 628 bytes, the .ns file is 16MB by
>   default.
>
> Each collection counts as a namespace, as does each index. Thus if
>   every collection had one index, we can create up to 12,000
>   collections. The --nssize parameter allows you to increase this limit
>   (see below).
>
> Be aware that there is a certain minimum overhead per collection -- a
>   few KB. Further, any index will require at least 8KB of data space as
>   the b-tree page size is 8KB. Certain operations can get slow if there
>   are a lot of collections and the meta data gets paged out.

So you won't be able to gracefully handle it if your users exceed the namespace limit. Also it won't be high on performance with the growth of your userbase.

UPDATE

For Mongodb 3.0 or above using WiredTiger storage engine, it will no longer be the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes personally I think having multiple collections in a DB keeps it nice and clean. The only thing I would worry about is the size of the collections. Collections are used by a lot of developers to cut up their db into, for example, posts, comments, users.

Sorry about my grammar and lack of explanation I'm on my phone